# Select unmatched records only

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table below in Oracle

`Table1`

```
ROW-ID | Fname   |LName
1      | P1      | xxxx
1      | P1      | xxxx
1      | P2      | xxxx
1      | P2      | xxxy
2      | P1      | xxxx
3      | P2      | xxxx
```

My Output should be only select for same ROW-ID if there will be changes in FName OR LName.

```
ROW-ID | Fname   |LName
1      | P2      | xxxx
1      | P2      | xxxy
```

Comment: The question is incomplete. "A change" makes sence only with a order of things. What is the order? With your definition, every row qualifies to enter in the output. Also, did you try something or search for possible solutions?

Comment: If ROW-ID is same and LName or FName is changed then will pick that row.

Comment: Oracle tables are "heap" tables. There is no order of rows. The row with xxxy may come first sometimes. So, to define "change", you need to define an order or rows.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using:

- **CASE**
- **LAG()**

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 1 row_id, 'P1' Fname, 'xxxx' Lname FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1 row_id, 'P1' Fname, 'xxxx' Lname FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1 row_id, 'P2' Fname, 'xxxx' Lname FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1 row_id, 'P2' Fname, 'xxxy' Lname FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 2 row_id, 'P1' Fname, 'xxxx' Lname FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 3 row_id, 'P2' Fname, 'xxxx' Lname FROM dual
  8  )
  9  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
 10  SELECT row_id,
 11    Fname,
 12    Lname
 13  FROM
 14    (SELECT row_id,
 15      Fname,
 16      Lname,
 17      CASE
 18        WHEN lag(Fname) over(partition BY row_id order by Fname) <> Fname
 19        OR   lag(Lname) over(partition BY row_id order by Lname) <> Lname
 20        THEN 1
 21        ELSE 0
 22      END rn
 23    FROM sample_data
 24    )
 25  WHERE rn = 1;

    ROW_ID FNAME LNAME
---------- ----- -----
         1 P2    xxxx
         1 P2    xxxy

SQL>
```

**How it works?**

Basically, you want to see when the change happened while traversing the rows in an order. So, **LAG()** tells you whether the change happened while comparing it with previous row. This is where **CASE** helps you to compare. Since you wanted any of the columns, `Fname` or `Lname`, I have added an **OR** condition.